# How complex and nested json dataset works with pyspark

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, pyspark, dataset

I have a very complex data and was handled in scala in databricks.
I want to convert that scala to python and that should work with the data given which is in JSON

Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._                        
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._                     

val jsonSchema = new StructType()
        .add("battery_level", LongType)
        .add("c02_level", LongType)
        .add("cca3",StringType)
        .add("cn", StringType)
        .add("device_id", LongType)
        .add("device_type", StringType)
        .add("signal", LongType)
        .add("ip", StringType)
        .add("temp", LongType)
        .add("timestamp", TimestampType)

// define a case class

case class DeviceData (id: Int, device: String)

// create some sample data

val eventsDS = Seq (

(0, """{"device_id": 0, "device_type": "sensor-ipad", "ip": "68.161.225.1", "cca3": "USA", "cn": "United States", "temp": 25, "signal": 23, "battery_level": 8, "c02_level": 917, "timestamp" :1475600496 }"""),

 (1, """{"device_id": 1, "device_type": "sensor-igauge", "ip": "213.161.254.1", "cca3": "NOR", "cn": "Norway", "temp": 30, "signal": 18, "battery_level": 6, "c02_level": 1413, "timestamp" :1475600498 }"""),

 (2, """{"device_id": 2, "device_type": "sensor-ipad", "ip": "88.36.5.1", "cca3": "ITA", "cn": "Italy", "temp": 18, "signal": 25, "battery_level": 5, "c02_level": 1372, "timestamp" :1475600500 }"""),

 (3, """{"device_id": 3, "device_type": "sensor-inest", "ip": "66.39.173.154", "cca3": "USA", "cn": "United States", "temp": 47, "signal": 12, "battery_level": 1, "c02_level": 1447, "timestamp" :1475600502 }""")).toDF("id", "device").as[DeviceData]

display(eventsDS)
```

[Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FwVU.png)

Now i want to implement above code in pyspark.
I have done someway but stuck in Seq as no Seq is in python.
How to handle this sample data in pyspark?

Python code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from dataclasses import dataclass

scSpark = SparkSession.builder.appName("complex data types").getOrCreate()
#Creating JSON schema
jsonSchema = StructType([
  StructField("battery_level", LongType(), True), 
  StructField("c02_level", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("c02_level", LongType(), True),
  StructField("cca3",StringType(), True),
  StructField("cn", StringType(), True),
  StructField("device_id", LongType(), True),
  StructField("device_type", StringType(), True),
  StructField("signal", LongType(), True),
  StructField("ip", StringType(), True),
  StructField("temp", LongType(), True),
  StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
])
#Create a Dataset from the above schema
@dataclass
class DeviceData(object):
  id: int
  device: str
```

Now i don't understand what to write next. 
I want the output like in the image i was provided.

My main motive is to https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/complex-nested-data.html convert all scala into pyspark. That will solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to use the json schema. `json.load()` the json file and that will give you a nice python dictionary with the data. The data in the example isn't really that complex actually. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: In my case, i have to explicitly define the schema. And i want to show the above data using python code. I have no idea how to handle **Seq**. It is a sample data only. I have more nested lists and json inside json like structure. I will handle that part, if it is solved in this part. Thanks.

Comment: there is a package called jsonschema https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ that allows you to validate json but as for generating json, I'd just create classes to handle the json. If it needs to be done that way for something spark related, maybe tag the post as such

Comment: Thanks. It is more related to pyspark. So edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scala `Seq` is most comparable to a python `list`:

```
eventsDS = (sql.createDataFrame(
            [(0, """{"device_id": 0, "device_type": "sensor-ipad", "ip": "68.161.225.1", "cca3": "USA", "cn": "United States", "temp": 25, "signal": 23, "battery_level": 8, "c02_level": 917, "timestamp" :1475600496 }"""),
             (1, """{"device_id": 1, "device_type": "sensor-igauge", "ip": "213.161.254.1", "cca3": "NOR", "cn": "Norway", "temp": 30, "signal": 18, "battery_level": 6, "c02_level": 1413, "timestamp" :1475600498 }"""),
             (2, """{"device_id": 2, "device_type": "sensor-ipad", "ip": "88.36.5.1", "cca3": "ITA", "cn": "Italy", "temp": 18, "signal": 25, "battery_level": 5, "c02_level": 1372, "timestamp" :1475600500 }"""),
             (3, """{"device_id": 3, "device_type": "sensor-inest", "ip": "66.39.173.154", "cca3": "USA", "cn": "United States", "temp": 47, "signal": 12, "battery_level": 1, "c02_level": 1447, "timestamp" :1475600502 }""")],
            ['id', 'device']))

eventsDS.show()                                                                                                                                                                                           

+---+--------------------+                                                      
| id|              device|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|{"device_id": 0, ...|
|  1|{"device_id": 1, ...|
|  2|{"device_id": 2, ...|
|  3|{"device_id": 3, ...|
+---+--------------------+
```

In pyspark SQL, the case class is not necessary.

```
eventsDS.printSchema()                                                                                                                                                                                    

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- device: string (nullable = true)
```